# Telethon bot: Create a WebView (webapp) button

Tags: python, telethon

I am trying to create a message, from a Telegram bot, with a button to open a WebApp.

Similarly to [this issue](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/3807) (closed because offtopic), the types are included - but whenever I send a message, like this:

```py
await client.send_message(
                    event.chat_id,
                    "Test",
                    buttons=[
                        types.KeyboardButtonWebView(
                            "press me",
                            "https://google.com",
                        )
                    ],
                )
```

I'm getting back a
`telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ButtonTypeInvalidError: The type of one of the buttons you provided is invalid (caused by SendMessageRequest)`

PS. I've tried in groups or private messages - I've tried "[newthon](https://github.com/Disk6969/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/tl/custom/button.py#L310)" - tried the SimpleWebView and passing the button in arrays and matrix.

Comment: Make sure the bot is correctly configured in [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). Be sure to check out the docs for [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) and [Web Apps for Bots](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps). I don't know much about this topic in particular, but generally, Telegram's HTTP bot API can always translate in some way to Telethon (if they can do it, Telethon can too).

Comment: I think the bot is configured correctly - for example using the `KeyboardButtonUrl` that takes the same parameters works fine.

Comment: I was expecting the `KeyboardButtonWebView` to receive a `WebAppInfo` as a parameter - but I'm not sure how I can verify or override the types

Comment: Perhaps you can send such a message with HTTP Bot API, and then fetch the message with Telethon (via the same bot itself or the user account who received the message) to learn how it's configured.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, spent a lot of time to solve this case.

You can send not reply webapp button by `KeyboardButtonSimpleWebView`:

```
await client.send_message(
    event.chat_id,
    "Test",
    buttons=[
        types.KeyboardButtonSimpleWebView(
            "press me",
            "https://google.com",
        )
    ]
)
```

But in this kind of button telegram not send information about chat to web application. Strange design in my opinion. So, you need to use KeyboardButtonWebView for inline button, but there is a error in `telethon.tl.custom.button.Button._is_inline` method — no this class in checking if this button is inline or not, so it marks like not inline and error appear.

We need to construct `buttons` argument by ourself and it starts working.

```
await client.send_message(
    event.chat_id,
    "Test",
    buttons=types.ReplyInlineMarkup([
        types.TypeKeyboardButtonRow([
            types.KeyboardButtonWebView(
                'Test!',
                'htts://google.com'
            )
        ])
    ]))
```

Hope this helps.